# Export to a csv file

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv, plsqldeveloper

I try many times to export my result into .csv file but I'm always fail. I read lot of articles related in my problem.

Look at my query:

```
spool sample.csv

SELECT /*html*/(CODE_SALESROOM) POS_ID, (NAME_SALESROOM) POS_NAME
FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_SALESROOM
WHERE CODE_SALESROOM NOT IN ('XAP', 'XNA', '10001');

spool off;
```

The output of this, when I export in a csv file is only the query not the real result.

What's wrong in my command to export the result?

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: If your using oracle sql developer - right click on the result grid, choose Export and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your query returns values. You can set various parameters of Sql plus before spooling to get desired out put. Below is the list that I use before spooling. And since your are generating csv, it should be comma separated

```
set echo off
set termout off
set define off
set heading off
set pagesize 10000
set linesize 500
set feedback off
set verify off
set trimspool on

spool sample.csv

SELECT 'POS_ID,POS_NAME' from dual; -- header list

SELECT CODE_SALESROOM || ',' || NAME_SALESROOM
FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_SALESROOM
WHERE CODE_SALESROOM NOT IN ('XAP', 'XNA', '10001');

spool off;
```

You can modify the set parameters based on your requirement.

Comment: Nothing changes @San, I follow your command but when I open the csv file the query is inputted there not the result of the query

Comment: Is this query `SELECT CODE_SALESROOM || ',' || NAME_SALESROOM
FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_SALESROOM
WHERE CODE_SALESROOM NOT IN ('XAP', 'XNA', '10001');` returning something?

Comment: No, i get some error ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
01756. 00000 -  "quoted string not properly terminated"

Comment: Well some single quote is missing, check all the quotes in your `NOT IN` list. `SELECT CODE_SALESROOM, NAME_SALESROOM FROM OWNER_DWH.DC_SALESROOM WHERE CODE_SALESROOM NOT IN ('XAP', 'XNA', '10001');`

Comment: i think there's nothing missing any single quote in my query

Comment: Well every thing seems to be ok here, god knows why it not working at your end. With the same code I am unable to reproduce the error.